# Flask-socketio не всегда срабатывает отправка сообщений

Tags: python, websocket, flask, socket.io

Есть простой код:

```
class Chat(Namespace):

    def on_manager_connect(self, message):
        global managers
        managers = {'id': message['userId'], 'name': User.query.get(message['userId']).email, 'sid': request.sid, 'room': message['userId']}
        print(str(message['userId']) + ' was connected')

    def on_manager_joined(self, message):
        join_room(managers['room'])
        print(str(managers['id']) + ' joined the room')
        emit('manager_status', {'msg': managers['name'] + ' has entered the room.', 'time': time.strftime("%H:%M")}, room=managers['room'])

    def on_manager_text(self, message):
        redis_store.publish('msg', message['msg'])
        emit('manager_message', {'msg':  message['msg'], 'time': time.strftime("%H:%M"), 'name': managers['name']}, room=managers['room'])

    def on_manager_left(self, message):
        leave_room(managers['room'])    
        emit('manager_status', {'msg': managers['name'] + 'has left the room.', 'name': managers['name']}, room=managers['room'])
        print(managers['name'] + ' has left the room.')
```

Клиентская часть:

```
        socket_chat.on('manager_status', function(data) {
                $('#chat-box').append('<div class="chat_message_wrapper">' +
                '<div class="chat_user_avatar">' +
                '<a href="#" target="_blank" >' +
                '<img class="md-user-image" style="border-radius: 999px" alt="" title="" src="https://kak2z.ru/galavatars/images/9/561.png">' +
                '<!--img alt="" title=""  src="" class="md-user-image"-->' +
                '</a>' +
                '</div>' +
                '<ul class="chat_message last" id="chat-wrapper">' +
                '<li>' +
                '<p>' + data.msg + '</p>' +
                '<span class="chat_message_time">' + data.time + '</span>'+
                '</li>' +
                '</ul>' +
                '</div>');
            $('#chat').scrollTop($('#chat')[0].scrollHeight);
        });

        socket_chat.on('manager_message', function(data) {
                $('#chat-box').append('<div class="chat_message_wrapper">' +
                '<div class="chat_user_avatar">' +
                '<a href="#" target="_blank" >' +
                '<img class="md-user-image" style="border-radius: 999px" alt="" title="" src="https://kak2z.ru/galavatars/images/9/561.png">' +
                '<!--img alt="" title=""  src="" class="md-user-image"-->' +
                '</a>' +
                '</div>' +
                '<ul class="chat_message last" id="chat-wrapper">' +
                '<li>' +
                '<p>' + data.msg + '</p>' +
                '<span class="chat_message_time">' + data.time + '</span>'+
                '</li>' +
                '</ul>' +
                '</div>');
        });
```

Проблема заключается в том, что `on_manager_connect` срабатывает в 100 из 100 случаев (при каждой перезагрузке страницы, я получаю сообщение, которое выводит `print(str(message['userId']) + ' was connected')`, в то время как `on_manager_joined` срабатывает каждый 3-5й раз (каждую 3-5ю перезагрузку страницы).

Не понимаю в чём проблема.

Если кто-то сталкивался и знает, чем это может быть вызвано, очень прошу помочь.

**[EDIT]**

При этом, я ВСЕГДА получаю сообщение :

```
[2017-02-05 17:24:53 +0300] [6409] [ERROR] Error handling request
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/narnik/Программы/FlaskProjects/ttt/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/async.py", line 52, in handle
    self.handle_request(listener_name, req, client, addr)
  File "/home/narnik/Программы/FlaskProjects/ttt/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/async.py", line 114, in handle_request
    resp.close()
  File "/home/narnik/Программы/FlaskProjects/ttt/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/gunicorn/http/wsgi.py", line 423, in close
    self.send_headers()
  File "/home/narnik/Программы/FlaskProjects/ttt/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/gunicorn/http/wsgi.py", line 316, in send_headers
    tosend = self.default_headers()
  File "/home/narnik/Программы/FlaskProjects/ttt/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/gunicorn/http/wsgi.py", line 297, in default_headers
    elif self.should_close():
  File "/home/narnik/Программы/FlaskProjects/ttt/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/gunicorn/http/wsgi.py", line 230, in should_close
    if self.status_code < 200 or self.status_code in (204, 304):
```

Однако, [тут](https://github.com/miguelgrinberg/Flask-SocketIO/issues/223) говорится о том, что эта ошибка не мешает работе WebSockets.

Запускаю приложение следующим образом:

```
sudo gunicorn manage:app --worker-class eventlet -w 1 --bind 0.0.0.0:5000 --reload
```